# Matlab: how to create infinitly deep for-loops?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

So we are given with some `w` and we want to so something like such pseudocode:

```
u = zeros(size(w));
for o=1:length(size(w))
 for i=1:size(w)(1), 
  for j=1:size(w)(2), 
...
    for k=1:size(w)(length(size(w))),
        u(i, j, ..., k )=1/(exp((-w(i,j, ..., k )))+25);
    end
...
  end
 end
end
```

is such thing possible with Matlab and how to do it?

Comment: That's a `w` in the exponent, rather than a `z`, correct?

Comment: arrayfun works only for 2 dimensions tops=(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jonas's answer is the best option, however for a general-purpose code (one that @Jonas's 'matricized' answer does not apply), you can use a code-generation approach, for example:

```
fcode = fopen('manyForLoopsScript.m','w');
w = rand(2,3,4);
numLoops = length(size(w));
u = zeros(size(w));

% open the 'for' loops
for m = 1 : numLoops
    fprintf(fcode, 'for a%d = 1:size(w,%d)\n',m,m);
end

% the actuall 'stuff'
indStr = [];
for m = 1 : numLoops
    indStr = [indStr,sprintf('a%d,',m)];
end
indStr = indStr(1:end-1);
fprintf(fcode, ['u(' indStr ') = exp(-w(' indStr '));\n']);

% close the 'for' loops
for m = 1 : numLoops
    fprintf(fcode, 'end\n');
end
fclose(fcode);

manyForLoopsScript
```

Comment: Although valid, I would not recommend such approach... use vectorized-functions when possible, or just use *linear indices* if you have to

Answer (score 5):

This is certainly possible, but also not recommended, since it's very non-idiomatic.

For simplicity, I assume that there is a typo in your question and that it should say `exp(-w(i,j,...))`.

Then, `u` can be calculated as

```
u = exp(-w);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use recursion - write a function, that iterates over the desired variables, and calls itself each time.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to rewrite the function you want to apply to be **vectorized**, so that it is computed **element-wise** (the same way EXP built-in function works for scalar/vector/matrix input):

```
u = 1./(exp(-w)+25);
```

Otherwise, if you prefer a for-loop, all you need to do is to traverse the multi-dimensional input matrix using **linear indices** (in a column-major order), apply the function to each element, then `RESHAPE` the result back into the expected shape:

```
u = zeros(numel(w),1);
for i=1:numel(w)
    u(i) = 1 ./ ( exp(-w(i)) + 25 );
end
u = reshape(u, size(w));
```

This is basically what the `ARRAYFUN` functions does for you:

```
u = arrayfun(@(x) 1./(exp(-x)+25), w);
```

In the chance that you also need access to the actual indices while looping over the elements of the matrix, you could always get them with `IND2SUB` (which converts linear indices to subscripts), or even generate all of them with functions like `MESHGRID` and `NDGRID`...